# "~Ni" or "~De"?

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese

Should I use (に or で) for the following lines? Since they are time periods,  I thought に would be correct, according to [this page](https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/de-ni.html):

> Times
>
> The particle ni is usually used with times:
> Go-ji ni kaerimasu(５時にかえります), "I'll go home at five o'clock".
> The particle de may also be used to show the time when something
> finishes:
> (授業は５時で終ります) "The class finishes at five o'clock."

1-3節目はこの形式で書かれています。

> 赤は。。。/ 夕日の暖かさ / 色づく秋の葉 / 何とか何とか何とか

Concluding stanza:

> On a serene winter's eve / on a spring morn / on a hot summer's day / on a quiet autumn afternoon
> Red is the color of life.

最後のスタンザ [節]

> 穏やかな冬の夜に / 春の朝に / 暑い夏の日に / 静かな秋の午後に
> 赤は生活の色である。

Comment: I'm not good enough to translate for you, but I'd guess it would depend weather you are saying something IS AT some time or is something HAPPENING AT some time. Common way to differentiate them is that に is used to say "I'm at home" while で would be used to say "I'm at my home DOING something", since で kinda turns the bit before it into an adverb, describes some attribute of an action. Where it's happening or with what it is done and such: https://kawakawalearningstudio.com/all/how-to-differentiate-location-particles-%E3%81%A7de-%E3%81%ABni-and-%E3%81%B8e/

Comment: で as in ５時で授業が終わる is not locative but instrumental, which stands for amount that you do something with.

Answer (score 1):

に is correct for that type of time expression (夏の夕暮れに). で in 5時で終わる can be understood as 5時になったら終わる, but you can also use 5時に終わる. The nuance is slightly different (に sounds like it was planned to end at five, whereas で sounds like maybe the ending time depends on eg how much work is completed by that time etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what my reference book (A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar) has to say:

Xで can indicate that something lasts for a period of time up to X.

に can be used in place of で in this case. However, the nuance is different. When で is used, the nuance is that the event lasts up to X. When に is used, it simply indicates the time when X ends.

Further, when X indicates a duration of time, で indicates how long an action took, and に is ungrammatical.